# Laravel Delete (Integrity Constraint Violation)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to implement a delete on my controller but then I have this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails `` (`greatsup_wz`.`entryitems`, CONSTRAINT `entryitems_fk_check_entry_id` FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`) REFERENCES `entries` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `greatsup_wz`.`entries` where `id` = 686) ``

Here is a piece of my code:

```
$entryTable     =   DB::table(config("app.DB_ACCOUNTING").".entryitems")
                    ->where('entryref_id','=',100)->get();
foreach($entryTable as $entryTbl):
  DB::table(config("app.DB_ACCOUNTING").".entries")
  ->where('id','=',$entryTbl->entry_id)->delete(); // this is where my error occurred
endforeach;
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The constraints that you have added  will prevent data from being deleted. You need to update database schema. You need to add onDelete('cascade') in the entryitems migration

```
Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('columnName')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('columnName')->references('columnName')->on('relatedTableName')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```